Empty field in json file thorws org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: [FIELD_NOT_FOUND] No such struct field
Background
SparkSQL with Scala
Reading Json file to populate data to Delta table
Problem
Trying to read json using scala. The format is as follows
{
Key : "Value"
Components : [
 {
    id : 1,
    name : "Part 1",
    properties : {}
 }
 {
    id : 2,
    name : "Part 2",
    properties : {}

 }
]
}

Reading using select command as : withColumn("Properties", col("Components.properties"))

Exception : org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: [FIELD_NOT_FOUND] No such struct field 

Attempts / Observations

When dummy value is set even to the first component properties field it works fine

{
    id : 1,
    name : "Part 1",
    properties : { "a" : "b"}
 }

In this case it outputs value for component 1 and null for component 2

Tried setting option dropFieldIfAllNull while reading the file as follows

    val jsonData = spark.read.option("multiLine", true).option("mode", "PERMISSIVE").option("dropFieldIfAllNull", false).json("/home/phantom/Data.json").createOrReplaceTempView("Contract")


Version
Spark : 3.5.2
Scala : 2.12
OS : Ubuntu 24.04
Command :  spark-submit --class JsonParser --master local[3] target/scala-2.12/spark-json-parser_2.12-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Question
How to read empty value as NULL or Empty String ?
